# How to show\hide Commands conditionally in Visual Studio Extension

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-extensions, vsix

I am creating a Visual Studio Extension, which should perform following activities:

1. On Right Click of Project, should show a Command.
2. Specific command should be shown for specific project.

For Example:
[image]

I have added a Commands Menu where there are 2 Commands. But I want to show only 'Command for Proj ABC' when right clicked on ABC project and similarly 'Command for Proj XYZ' should be shown when right clicked on XYZ project.

Is this possible? How Can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add **DynamicVisibility** [CommandFlag](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/command-flag-element?view=vs-2019) in .vsct for your commands and set **Visible** status in your OnBeforeQueryStatus handler depending on which project is currently selected.

See [Change the text of a menu command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/changing-the-text-of-a-menu-command?view=vs-2019) for an example.

Comment: It works, but from second time. For example, If I run VS Experimental (Debugging) and open a solution in that instance and right click on any project, it shows all commands. But when I click on any command and then right click on any project, at that time proper commands are shown.

Comment: @EnigmaticJohn It sounds like your extension is not loaded until you click on your commands. You may want to add the ProvideAutoLoadAttribute https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/loading-vspackages?view=vs-2019

Comment: `[ProvideAutoLoad(UIContextGuids.SolutionExists, PackageAutoLoadFlags.BackgroundLoad)]` this worked. However it takes around 30 seconds to take effect after opening the solution. Thanks.